# Dynamically creating page definitions in Cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I've been looking around the CherryPy documentation, but can't quite get my head around what I want to do. I suspect it might be more of a Python thing than a CherryPy thing...

My current class looks something like this:

```
import managerUtils

class WebManager:
    def A(self, **kwds):
        return managerUtils.runAction("A", kwds)
    A.enabled = True

    def B(self, **kwds):
        return managerUtils.runAction("B", kwds)
    B.enabled = True

    def C(self, **kwds):
        return managerUtils.runAction("C", kwds)
    C.enabled = True
```

Obviously there's a lot of repetition in here.

in managerUtils.py, I have a dict that's something like:

```
actions = {'A': functionToRunForA,
           'B': functionToRunForB,
           'C': functionToRunForC}
```

Okay, so that's a slightly simplistic view of it, but I'm sure you get the idea.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
import managerUtils

class WebManager:
    def __init__(self):
        for action in managerUtils.actions:
            f = registerFunction(action)
            f.enabled = True
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

One answer suggested doing:

```
class WebManager:
    def index(self, action, **kwds):
        return managerUtils.runAction(action, kwds)
    index.enabled = True
```

That picks up, I believe:

```
http://webserver/?action&kwds
```

Rather than what I want, which is:

```
http://webserver/action?kwds
```

When I do what you suggest, I get the following 404 error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond
    cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 227, in __call__
    raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/myAction' was not found.")
```

Comment: I think showing URLs with 'action' in their paths as an example is confusing (especially since the argument name in the proposed solution is also called, action.) At the top of the question the actions were 'A', 'B', and 'C'.  So the examples should have used one of those.  For example:  `http://webserver/?B&kwds` and `http://webserver/B?kwds`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class WebManager:
    def default(self, action, **kwds):
        return managerUtils.runAction(action, kwds)
    default.exposed = True
```

Two notes about why this is different than other answers:

1. `.exposed` is the correct attribute for publishing methods, not `.enabled`
2. the `index` method is the only one which does *not* allow positional arguments like "action". Use a `default` method instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Let me give that one a go!

The exposed/enabled thing was a typo on my part - my initial setup (the top block of my question) was using "exposed" - I just mis-typed when writing it in that generic way.

Will give "default" a go now - thanks!

Comment: It helps to understand that, like _index_, _default_ is a special method name in CherryPy page handler classes.  One might not know this since the _default_ method gets little coverage in the CherryPy documentation.  The _default_ method is a fallback method which is called if no other method matches the URL path.  It matches the partial path associated with its mount point.  The remaining, unmatched, part of the path is passed into the _default_ method as a series of positional arguments.